# How to add bottom border to tableview section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm using the following function to determine the tableview section header in my app:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
    var title: UILabel = UILabel()
     title.text = "something" 
     // Add a bottomBorder
     var border = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,1))
     border.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
     title.addSubview(border)
}
```

and the following section to determine the tableview section header height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

How can I add a bottom border to the section?

Comment: Add a little to the height.  In the view-returning method, return a taller view, but give it a shorter subview with a contrasting backgroundColor that contains whatever you want on the header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create UIView which will act as a border and then add it:

```
var border = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,40,self.view.bounds.width,1))
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
headerView.addSubview(border)
```

`headerView` is your custom view that you actually create

**EDIT**

```
 var headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,40))
 var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
 title.text = "something" 
 // Add a bottomBorder
 var border = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,39,self.view.bounds.width,1))
 border.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
 headerView.addSubview(border)
 headerView.addSubview(title)
 return headerView
```

**EDIT**

`CGRectMake` is not available anymore from Swift 3.0. Use `CGRect` instead

Comment: Thanks, I tried to it with no success, I added my code to the question, can you assist?

Comment: Sure, You are adding the border to the UILabel, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but now I can see only the border and I can't see any text, why?

Comment: Swift 4: let border = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 39, width: self.view.bounds.width,height: 1))
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        headerView.addSubview(border)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

This worked for me. In viewForHeaderInSection:

```
  let headerView = UIView()

    let borderTop = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 1.0))
    borderTop.backgroundColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 5/255, green: 16/255, blue: 28/255, alpha: 1.0)
    headerView.addSubview(borderTop)

    let borderBottom = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:40, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 1.0))
    borderBottom.backgroundColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 5/255, green: 16/255, blue: 28/255, alpha: 1.0)
    headerView.addSubview(borderBottom)
```

You can adjust top and bottom position depending on you header high. y=0 for top and x=40 for bottom border works for me. Hopes this helps. Good luck.

If you want to customize the rest of the header:

```
 let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 9, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))

    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Trebuchet MS", size: 19)

    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 254/255, green: 170/255, blue: 25/255, alpha: 1.0)

    headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)

    headerLabel.sizeToFit()

    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
```