# Adding bottom border for default section header of UITableView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

In the table view I am having few sections, I am using the default section header of the table view, I simply set the title and height using the following methods.

```
public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    return sectionHeaders[Convert.ToInt32(section)];
}

public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    return 70;
}
```

I want to set bottom border for the section header.

[I searched and tried this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460625/6866139) but it simply gives a transparent header with red border, and there is no header title which I set in the `TitleForHeader` method. Is there any way to set bottom border for the default section header.

Answer (score 1):

You can override **GetViewForHeader** method and create your own view and customise it as per your requirement instead of default view like this:

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    var headerView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, (float)tableView.Bounds.Width, 70));

    var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(15, 35, (float)tableView.Bounds.Width - 100, 15));
    label.TextColor = UIColor.Gray;
    label.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 12f);
    label.Text = @"Sample Title"; //sectionHeaders[Convert.ToInt32(section)];
    headerView.AddSubview(label);

    var bottomBorder = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 69, (float)tableView.Bounds.Width, 1));
    bottomBorder.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    headerView.AddSubview(bottomBorder);

    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Here we are creating a new header view with a label. Even without this only by setting the TitleForHeader I am getting the text in exact position and size. Isn't there any way to set border for that default header rather than creating a new view inside the GetViewForHeader method